# How to correct heteroskedasticity in linear model of probability?

Tags: regression, bias, robust

If we fit linear regression model to data, where dependent variable is binary response, then heteroskedasticity occours, how to correct for this issue ? Is it different then correcting for heteroskedasticity with continous dependent variable (can we make it more efficiently using information that dependent variable is binary) ?

Comment: Do you mean estimators of the true effects of the variables? Why do you think they are biased? Is it just a question about omitted variable bias?

Comment: @Michael Mayer4 thank you, I provided major correction to my question

Comment: Okay. Now the question makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2):

The problem  of heteroscedasticity in linear probability model can be resolved by transforming the main liner probability model by dividing it through by weights(then the transformed error term will be a homoscedastic one).Now estimate the transformed equation by OLS (which is in this case nothing but the weighted least squares, as weights are being used in transforming the model).